# Can one OpenVPN client.conf file configure multiple users' access?

Tags: openvpn

I've got the OpenVPN Ubuntu client installed as a service on my laptop.  There is currently one `cert` entry and one `key` entry in `/etc/openvpn/client.conf`.  I would either like to have one `client.conf` per user of the laptop or have a different `key` and `cert` for each user in `client.conf`; or, as a fallback, can I restrict OpenVPN to one particular user?  Are any of those options possible?  I can't see anything useful in the [how-to guide](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/how-to/#creating-configuration-files-for-server-and-clients), though the section I've linked does perhaps suggest that *something* like what I'm asking might be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure openvpn connections on a per user basis under the network settings for that user.

Remove the service and add key/certificate for the users you want

Comment: Thanks, can you point me at the file(s) I should be editing?  I hadn't realised the network settings were (or could be) per-user!

Comment: Not sure which files (I'm away from my Linux machine at the moent), I would just add the a new VPN connection from the "Network" entry in the "Settings" app. You may need to install something like `network-manager-openvpn` to get the right options to show up.

Comment: Ah, OK, so that's a different way of running the VPN then.  I have it as a service at the moment, but it sounds like it should be configured as a network connection instead, and then I turn that on or off.  I found [this](https://torguard.net/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=53) which helped me get it configured.  I already had `network-manager-openvpn` installed.